# When does a nonlinear bijective map send independent vectors to independent vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bijection, or say a diffeomorphism for convenience. If $\varphi$ is a linear map, it clearly maps linearly independent vectors to linear independent vectors.

My question is: Suppose $\varphi$ is not necessarily linear, is there any condition that might guarantee that $\varphi$ sends linearly independent vectors to linear independent vectors (maybe not working for all vectors, but for vectors with small norm)? For example, if the Hessian of $\varphi$ is "suitably small" (needs concrete description), $\varphi$ should be close to $d\varphi$ and there might be a positive answer.

Many thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "$\varphi$ should be close to $d\varphi$"

Comment: Let $J$ denote the Jacobian of $\varphi$ at $0$. For $x$ close to zero, we have $\varphi(x) - \varphi(0) = Jx + o(\|x\|)$. It follows that for $x_1,\dots,x_n$ with $\|x_i\| < \epsilon$ for all $i$, we have (using the differentiability of the determinant function)
$$
\det [\varphi(x_1) - \varphi(0) \ \ \cdots \ \ \varphi(x_n) - \varphi(0)] = \\
\det[Jx_1 + o(\epsilon) \ \ \cdots \ \ Jx_n + o(\epsilon)] = \\
\det\left(J[x_1 \ \ \cdots \ \ x_n] + o(\epsilon) \right) = \\
\det\left(J[x_1 \ \ \cdots \ \ x_n]\right) + o(\epsilon) = \\
\det(J) \det([x_1\ \ \cdots \ \ x_n]) + o(\epsilon).
$$

Comment: So, it indeed must be the case that for some neighborhood of zero, the vectors $\varphi(x_1)-\varphi(0),\dots,\varphi(x_n) - \varphi(0)$ will be linearly independent. However, if we are "unlucky", it might hold that $\varphi(x_1),\dots,\varphi(x_n)$ fails to be linearly independent.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you, I should have said $\varphi(0)=0$ to carry out this argument. However I do not think everything is OK. $\det(J)\det[x]+o(\|x\|)$ is not necessarily nonzero when $x$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I meant when $[x]=[x_1\cdots x_n]$ is an invertible matrix with small norm.

Comment: You're right, that was a silly oversight. It's a tricky problem then